# Azure memory size -- what gives?

Tags: azure, memory

OK,

I am setting up my first Azure VM, the only images available are basically windows server.

Why are their servers so low on memory until you get to pretty big $$$?

Are there any of us who would straight faced tell a client that they should run a windows server with .75 GB of ram?

Can I run basic applications on the small machines or should I not waste my time?

Thank you,

Joe

Comment: Questions about VM sizes etc belong on ServerFault. Rants about use of your time don't fit here.

Comment: Noted.  I forgot about server fault, probably because there are so many questions about Azure here that relate to infrastructure type issues.  Comment about the rant however was not needed and wasteful of time.  I did not rant.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure where you're looking at, but there's definitely more than Windows images in there (Ubunto, CoreOs, CentOS, Suse...)

Not to mention that you also have the [VM Depot](https://vmdepot.msopentech.com/List/Index)

extra small instances make good for some light load like acting as a witness in HA setups, or even running small web sites...

depends on what you run on it.

you'd know better what your app requires.

Comment: I apologize, I meant as far as windows operating systems go.  meaning there are not windows 7, 8 etc.

Comment: You cannot run Windows client software (Windows 7, 8, etc) in Azure for production desktop use (only for testing purposes with an MSDN subscription). Cloud-hosted desktops must run on Windows Server using RDP. See: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/29/windows-client-images-on-azure/

Comment: if you filter using the MSDN tick box on the lower left corner, you'll see Windows 7/8 images. but as Simon mentioned above, it's for Testing purposes only.

Comment: Thanks folks.  Useful info - I appreciate it, when just starting out there is SO much out there to dig through....